# Jenkins deploy plugin deletes app context xml file

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, tomcat6

I am using Jenkins (v1.4.87) and have the [deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) (v1.10) to create a job that deploys a built war file into tomcat 6.

The deployment is running successfully, the war is being deployed ok.

Here is the plugin configuration part of the job:

*(I have not included the real server details for obvious reasons)*

[image]

The problem is that somewhere along the way, the application context file is renamed to `appname.xml.bak` and left in that state. Therefore the application fails to start because tomcat cannot find the context file it expects for the application any longer.

To remedy this I have to log into the server where the context file is located and rename the backup back to its original file name `appname.xml`.

It feels like the deploy plugin may be getting to a point where it should handle this. I would expect it to either make a copy of the context file called `appname.xml.bak` or rename the backup back to the correct file name.

I cannot find any documentation that lists out the phases that the plugin goes through so I cannot confirm if this behavior is expected or not. I am left with the only option to download the [plugin code from Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/deploy-plugin/tree/deploy-1.10) and figure it out myself.

Have I missed something obvious maybe?

**UPDATED:**

I have since updated to Jenkins v2.32.3 and I have the same issue with the deploy plugin. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: From what I can tell the Tomcat manage webapp doesn't let you also supply the context.xml as a file upload, only as a URL, which seems to be unhelpful. The only approach that has worked for us is to push it to the server SSH then invoke a script to do the deployment. We store our wars in $CATALINE_BASE/wars and these are pointed to by the context.xml file.